# Можно ли скачать этот скрипт и скинуть его в папку JS?

Tags: javascript

www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js

Comment: О_0 Можно, сообщество даёт добро. Скачивайте и кидайте его в папку.

Comment: Ну в смысле работать оно будет потом?)

Comment: @pwnz22, смотря что подразумевать под словом «работать». если клиенты будут получать этот файл от вас, а не от google, аналитика по вашему сайту, вполне возможно, вскоре (или сразу) перестанет собираться на google-вских серверах. если для вас это несущественно — проверьте, пожалуйста, и сможете сами ответить на свой вопрос.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, Попробую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google учитывает где лежит его файл, если например у вас на сервере http://test.com/analytics.js, то настройки[CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) на стороне google, не  пустят данные. Чем он вам мешает?

Comment: какие-то странные вещи вы говорите. Всё гораздо проще.